# How to pass an array of primitives as varargs?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

I'm stuck trying to pass an array of primitives (in my case an `int[]`) to a method with varargs.

Let's say:

```
    // prints: 1 2
    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", new String[] { "1", "2"}));
    // fails with java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%s'
    System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", new int[] { 1, 2 }));
```

Note however that the first line gets the following warning:

> Type String[] of the last argument to method format(String, Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.

Note also I don't input the array with a constructor, but I get it from the enclosing method, whose signature I can't change, like:

```
private String myFormat(int[] ints) {
    // whatever format it is, it's just an example, assuming the number of ints
    // is greater than the number of the format specifiers
    return String.format("%s %s %s %s", ints);
}
```

Comment: Note that `String.format` is not your method here. Its a nethod of `java.lang.String`.

Comment: How are you constructing the `String.format` statement? Does it contain a constant number of %s parameter? If so, it can also contain a constant number of parameters, instead of an array.

Comment: If you know the number of the required `int`s, spell them out, as: `String.fromat("%d %d", ints[0], ints[1])`, as those `int`s will be autoboxed...

Comment: I clarified the code in order to disambiguate between the String.format and my "format" method.

Comment: +Usagi Miyamoto: it's intended to not known the actual number of parameters... and supposed you have 100's ints, would you type all those ints[i]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `String.format(String format, Object... args)` is waiting an `Object` varargs as parameter. Since `int` is a primitive, while `Integer` is a java `Object`, you should indeed convert your `int[]` to an `Integer[]`.

To do it, you can use nedmund answer if you are on Java 7 or, with Java 8, you can one line it:

`Integer[] what = Arrays.stream( data ).boxed().toArray( Integer[]::new );`

or, if you don't need to have an `Integer[]`, if an `Object[]` is enough for your need, you can use:

`Object[] what = Arrays.stream( data ).boxed().toArray();`

Comment: So basically what you're saying is that an ``int`` is boxed to an ``Integer`` while an ``int[]`` is not boxed to an ``Integer[]``, so I have to the cast/conversion by myself, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you got the idea

Comment: The solution is perfect. Note however there is still a warning: ``Type Integer[] of the last argument to method format(String, Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation.``

Comment: Yes, but you can safely ignore this warning. Compilater is not that clever

Comment: Finally opted for this shorter form: ``Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().toArray()``

Answer (score 4):

You can use the wrapper class `Integer` instead, i.e.

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", new Integer[] { 1, 2 }));
```

This is how you would cast an existing `int[]` array:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2 };

Integer[] castArray = new Integer[ints.length];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) {
    castArray[i] = Integer.valueOf(ints[i]);
}

System.out.println(String.format("%s %s", castArray));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm in Java8.

Answer (score 0):

int varargs to object varargs, creating a formater with blank separator

```
 private void method( int ... values) {
        String.format(StringUtils.repeat("%d", " ", values.length),  Arrays.stream( values ).boxed().toArray());
 }
```

Comment: Irrelevant answer. The number of placeholders `%s` in the pattern for the `String.format` is disjointed from the actual number of ints; check the comment `whatever format it is, it's just an example`

Comment: I think it's not irrelevant, sometimes more complete answers can help another people who reads your question, removing the need to create another question just if for they the number os placeholders may be relevant (or another details)